# systemctl: filter by a pattern in unit names

Tags: systemd, systemctl

When executed with no arguments, `systemctl` outputs a nice table displaying the status of every unit in the system:

```
$ systemctl

  UNIT                       LOAD   ACTIVE     SUB       DESCRIPTION
  console-setup.service      loaded active     exited    Set console font and keymap
  cron.service               loaded active     running   Regular background program processing daemon
  dbus.service               loaded active     running   D-Bus System Message Bus
  myapp-component1.service   loaded active     running   Application - Component 1
● myapp-component2.service   loaded active     failed    Application - Component 2
  [...]
  dbus.socket                loaded active     running   D-Bus System Message Bus Socket
  myapp-socket1.socket       loaded active     listening Application - a socket
  [...]
  fstrim.timer               loaded active     waiting   Discard unused blocks once a week
  myapp-periodic.timer       loaded active     waiting   Application - periodic job
  [...]
```

My application consists of a bunch of services (and timers, and sockets, ...) coordinated by systemd.
For every subcomponent of the application, the unit name starts with "myapp-".
I want to use `systemctl` to observe at a glance the status of my application components.

Is there a way of asking `systemctl` to only list units whose name matches a pattern (for example `'myapp-*'`)?

```
$ systemctl <some-option-asking-for 'myapp-*`>

  UNIT                       LOAD   ACTIVE     SUB       DESCRIPTION
  myapp-component1.service   loaded active     running   Application - Component 1
● myapp-component2.service   loaded active     failed    Application - Component 2
  myapp-socket1.socket       loaded active     listening Application - a socket
  myapp-periodic.timer       loaded active     waiting   Application - periodic job
```

**Note**: I am interested in a way to ask `systemctl` itself to filter the result set. Grepping and reformatting (for example via `column -t`) the complete `systemctl` output has edge cases i'd rather avoid.

Comment: most unit commands for `systemctl` supports pattern arguments. E.g `systemctl list-units "myapp-*"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`systemctl`’d default command is `list-units`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#list-units%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6), and that takes a pattern as optional argument, so

```
systemctl list-units 'myapp-*'
```

will do what you’re after.

Many `systemctl` commands support patterns; for example

```
systemctl status 'myapp-*'
```

will show the status of all units starting with “myapp-”.

Comment: Thanks for that! What I was missing is that `systemctl` default command is `list-units`, indeed.

Since I am also interested in knowing if some submodules are failing, the final command that I am going to use is:

`systemctl list-units 'myapp-*' --all`